# Facing issue while adding radio button in react - input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
  render() {
    let radioid = this.props.radioid;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.props.options.map(function(option) {
          return (
            <div key={radioid} className="column">
              <input type="radio" name={radioid} value={option}>
                <label>{option}</label>
              </input>
            </div>
          );
         })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

*For example options is a list of elements like A, B, C, D*

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As per the error, the input tag should not have any children, take the label out of input closure tag

```
render() {
    let radioid = this.props.radioid;
    return (
        <div className="row">
        {this.props.options.map(function(option) {
            return (
            <div key={radioid} className="column">
                <label>{option}</label>
                <input type="radio" name={radioid} value={option}/>
            </div>
            );
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In react inputs have to end with a single tag, not like

```
<input type="submit">Submit</input>
```

so write

```
<input />
```

but this may show submit query so write

```
<input value="Submit or login or whatever you like">
```

There you go :)

Answer (score 4):

You get the error coz in input tag in `jsx` should be self closing, so after return always `jsx` script should write.

```
render() {
    let radioid = this.props.radioid;
    return (
        <div className="row">
        {this.props.options.map(function(option) {
            return (
            <div key={radioid} className="column">
                <label>{option}</label>
                <input type="radio" name={radioid} value={option}/>
            </div>
            );
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML elements such as `<area />`, `<br />`, and `<input />` are void elements which are only self-closing without any content.

Therefore, React will throw an exception if you set either children or dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop for a void element.

So, instead of writing this as

```
<div key={radioid} className="column">
   <input type="radio" name={radioid} value={option}>
      <label>{option}</label>
   </input>
</div>
```

**write it like this:**

```
<div key={radioid} className="column">
   <input type="radio" name={radioid} value={option}/>
       <label>{option}</label>
</div>
```

Give a thumbs up if you like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a self-closing input tag like:

```
<input className="card-field-input" placeholder="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much!
I solved.

I have 2 tags "input", a type text and button but just the first didn't worked.

<input type="text" onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({coinAvalue:event.target.value})}}>
<input type="button" value="Converter"onClick={this.converter}>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30232750)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a select without the `as='select'` in my `<Form.Control>` call of **react-bootstrap**. So React rendered an `<input>` instead of a `<select>`

```
<Form.Control as='select' >
    <option value="Buy">Buy</option>
    <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
</Form.Control>
```